# How can I expand the zoom levels for a feature type in an .mbtiles file?

Tags: mbtiles

I have a 51 GiB mbtiles file containing vector tiles for the entire world.

I would like a particular type of feature (railways) to be available at more distant zoom levels. At present, this feature is missing from zoom levels wider than 8 (i.e. 1–7).

It seems to me that the necessary information should be already contained within the file (since the closer zoom level information can be used to produce the more distant zoom level information).

Is there some existing tool which can modify the mbtiles file accordingly?

Comment: have you finally found solution to expand zoom?

Comment: Please don't post questions as answers.